# How do i put a mask on this heatmap?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, visualization, seaborn

I have created a heatmap of my whole dataset above, however now i want to create a heatmap for the 10 most correlated points to my target variable. I have printed the shape of the data and of the mask, they are both 10 x 10, however a i get this error:

```
ValueError: Mask must have the same shape as the data.
```

I have used a dummy dataset from kaggle as an example.

```
    corr = training.corr()

    mask = np.zeros_like(corr, dtype=np.bool)
    mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True

    f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 9))

    sns.heatmap(corr, mask=mask,vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0, center=0,
        square=True, linewidths=.5, cbar_kws={"shrink": .5})
```

The first part of my code (above) computed a heatmap of my whole dataset with a mask on the top half of the data.

```
    k = 10

    cols = corr.nlargest(k, 'SalePrice')['SalePrice'].index

    cm = np.corrcoef(training[cols].values.T)

    sns.set(font_scale=1.25)

    f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 9))

    mask2 = np.zeros_like(cm, dtype=np.bool)
    mask2[np.triu_indices_from(mask2)] = True

    hm = sns.heatmap(cm, vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0, mask=mask, cbar=True, 
    annot=True, square=True, fmt='.2f', annot_kws={'size': 10},
    yticklabels=cols.values, xticklabels=cols.values)

    plt.show()
```

This should output a heatmap with the top half (repeated values) masked.

Comment: Please post your whole code, we can't see what you're working with here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

emphasized texti have seen the error in my code, it was down to a really bad typo bug. I have put the error in '**' to indicate bold text writing (i put mask = mask - which is the mask of the previous data set and that is not the same shape). Thank you if you was working on it... Maybe there is a shorter method to get this code done, so please still share.

```
**mask2** = np.zeros_like(cm, dtype=np.bool)
**mask2**[np.triu_indices_from(mask2)] = True

hm = sns.heatmap(cm, vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0, mask=**mask**, cbar=True, 
annot=True, square=True, fmt='.2f', annot_kws={'size': 10},
yticklabels=cols.values, xticklabels=cols.values)
```